# Does ROS Groovy have any problems running on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does ROS Groovy have any problems running on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 12.10?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51472/does-ros-groovy-have-any-problems-running-on-virtualbox-with-ubuntu-12.10?/) by [shyamalschandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/2087/shyamalschandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2013-01-04**:
Could you be more specific about what you want to run in VirtualBox? Basic roscpp? Navigation? Rviz? Gazebo? etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general ROS programs run fine inside Virtual Box, except for programs which use hardware accelerated video. The effectiveness of accelerated video depends a lot on your setup, host and hardware.

The other thing to be careful about when working in a VM is the availability and connectivity of the networking.  The problems are mostly about making sure that you have configured things right, not that it won't work.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1